How to print a full Req body once using LogInterceptor in Flutter?
I need to Log a full requisition Body, one single time on each req that my system does. I'am using StringBuffer, Dio and LogInterceptor.
What happens:
My log is printing the building of the body, not the full body's req.
CODE:
if (kDebugMode) {
  StringBuffer logObject = StringBuffer();
  dio.interceptors.add(
    LogInterceptor(
      requestBody: true,
      responseBody: true,
      requestHeader: true,
      responseHeader: true,
      error: true,
      logPrint: (Object object) {
        logObject.writeln(object);
        djLogger.debug(
          content: "Value Custom DIO: ",
          value: logObject,
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}

What I've tried
I tried to log the logObject outside the dio.interceptors.add(), but the result of my log was Null.

You can simply use a log method for get full req body printed.
import 'dart:developer';

log('data: $data');


I'm using a personal Log... but your suggestion is not bad.
My case is a little more complex.. What happens is: the log is printing the building of the response body, that can make my application slower. I need to make a single log of every response body.
Thanks for your answer!!

Well I hope you are using a common network class to access the same dio instance for all your network calls. If yes, then you can try the following:
So, let's say you initialized a Dio object.
Dio dio = Dio();

You can add log or any type of interceptors to that dio object. For adding only one inteceptor, you can do the following:
dio.interceptors.add(Logging(dio));

Here is the logging interceptor class:
class Logging extends Interceptor {
  final Dio dio;

  Logging(this.dio);

  @override
  void onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) {
    log(
        'REQUEST[${options.method}] => PATH: ${options.path} \n Extras: ${options.extra} \n Headers: ${options.headers} \n Query: ${options.queryParameters} \n Body: ${options.data}');
    super.onRequest(options, handler);
  }

  @override
  void onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) {
    log(
        'RESPONSE[${response.statusCode}] => PATH: ${response.requestOptions.path} \n res:: ${json.encode(response.data)}');
    super.onResponse(response, handler);
  }

  @override
  void onError(DioException err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) {
    log(
        'ERROR[${err.response?.statusCode ?? 'Unknown Status Code'}] => PATH: ${err.requestOptions.path}');
    super.onError(err, handler);
  }
}

Hope this helps

Hi, I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. The log don't print the response because gives an async stack.
But thanks for your answer! This can help in some other case.
